# why isn't my selector work? text() return null

Tags: jquery, css

my html

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><span>item1</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>item2</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

my selector

```
var itemName = $('ul li').closest('a').find('span').text();
```

it return nothing.. I want it to be bind with the click event..

Comment: [Rereading the docs for .closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) would probably have identified the problem for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) is for finding ancestor elements, not descendent elements. Use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$('ul li:first').find('a span').text();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CHCWZ/)

Comment: and also.. `$('ul > li > a > span').text()`

Comment: it work but it return item1item2..

Comment: @ViolettaMccullough if you want the text of first `li` then also use [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector

Answer (score 1):

`.closest()` finds the closest ancestor.  You can just use:

```
var itemName = $('ul li a span').text();
```

If you want to bind something to the click event, you can use:

```
$('ul li a span').on("click", function() {
    // do the action
});
```

Comment: I want only ONE item..

Comment: which one, the first?  Then do $('ul li a:first span')...

Comment: You can actually put the :first selector on li, a, or span.  Doesn't matter in your case.